# How does service stack determine available services?

Tags: servicestack

I have several services defined with ServiceStack which are working correctly.  I have added a new one using the following request object

```cs
namespace LCS.Presentation.API.Model.DocumentTemplates
{
    [Authenticate]
    [Route("/document/{Type}/{Id}", "GET,PUT")]
    [Route("/document/{Type}", "POST")]
    public class UploadFileRequest : IReturn<UploadFileResponse>
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public string File { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have defined a response object:

```cs
public class UploadFileResponse : IResponseBase
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

and written stubs for the services:

```cs
public class UploadFileService : Service
{
    private ICoreLoggingService Logger { get; set; }

    public UploadFileService(ICoreLoggingService logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }
    public UploadFileResponse Post(UploadFileRequest request)
    {
        Logger.Debug("Got POST file request: {0}", request); 
        var response = new UploadFileResponse();
        return response;
    }

    public UploadFileResponse Put(UploadFileRequest request)
    {
        Logger.Debug("Got PUT file request: {0}", request);
        var response = new UploadFileResponse();
        return response;
    }

    public UploadFileResponse Get(UploadFileRequest request)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, when I go to the metadata page (/api/metadata), I do not see the UploadFileRequest service listed with my other services.

ServiceStack is configured to be rooted at /api, and all my other services correctly show up in the metadata page as being configured to use that route.

What am I missing that is causing ServiceStack to not see this as an available service?

Comment: They should show up automatically by default. Do you have services split up across multiple assemblies? If so see the [Modularizing services wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services#modularizing-services-in-multiple-assemblies) to show how to reference multiple Assembly dlls in your AppHost.

Comment: The services are all in the same assembly.  I expected to see the new one show up automatically, which is why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I pasted the code into a test project and was able to see the service on the metadata page. Are your your request or service classes or their base classes/interfaces decorated with any attributes not shown in the code here? What version of ServiceStack are you using? Do you set `EndpointHostConfig.DebugMode` to true or false?

Comment: @esker There are no other attributes on the classes.  I'm using version 3.9.59.0 of service stack.  I had not set DebugMode at all, I don't believe.  I set it to true in my AppHost like this:       
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig(){ DebugMode = true });
after reading your comment, but this didn't change anything.

Comment: Shot in the dark but have you registered `ICoreLoggingService` with your container? Maybe SS is having trouble filling the dependency and eats the exception?

Comment: @Mike Nope, that's not it.  I have other services that have the same constructor and they work.  Nonetheless, I tried taking it out and it had not effect.

Comment: Few things I've done when I run into this issue: 1) Add typeof(UploadFileService).Assembly to the assemblies array passed to the base class to explicitly try to load it 2) In UploadFileService class make sure you are referencing 'ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service' not 'System.Web.Services.Description.Service' 3) If running through Visual Studio, stop IIS Express to force 'Application_Start' to be run.

Comment: Thanks, trying (1) made it work and made me realize that I was wrong when I told @mythz that the services weren't split across multiple assemblies.  Moving the service into the correct assembly made it work immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Copying out from comments so it's easier to find, more readable and accurate*

Few things I've done when I run into this issue:

**1** - In your `AppHost` class add `typeof(UploadFileService).Assembly` to the assemblies array passed to the base class to explicitly try to load it

**2** - <strike>In UploadFileService class make sure you are referencing '`ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service`' not '`System.Web.Services.Description.Service`'</strike> This is not possible since a class can't inherit from `System.Web.Services.Description.Service`

**3** - If running through Visual Studio, stop IIS Express to force 'Application_Start' to be run.